# Extract a value from s3 bucket meta file

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, bucket

I read a file from S3 Bucket using `obj.get()['Body'].read()` and 
this returned

`b'[{ "version": "v1", "timeDelta": 0.0, "artist": "", "title": "text="Spot Block End" amgTrackId="9876543"", "timestamp": "1586453290376" }]'`

I would like to extract the value of the timestamp key.

I stored a few .meta files in my s3 bucket, I need to check each of my .meta file has a timestamp

Answer (score 1):

This is not in json format. It seems like you need to escape the " in the title key

```
"title": "text=\"Spot Block End\" amgTrackId=\"9876543\""
```

Like this.

Maybe you can try to use regex to do it for you.

*EDIT:*

```
import json
import re

input = b'[{ "version": "v1", "timeDelta": 0.0, "artist": "", "title": "text="Spot Block End" amgTrackId="9876543"", "timestamp": "1586453290376" }]'
input = input.decode('utf-8')

match = re.findall('(?<=\"title\": \").*\"(?=\")',input)[0]
escaped_match = json.dumps(match)
input = input.replace(match,escaped_match[1:-1])

print(json.loads(input))
```

Take a look at this code, it's a bit ugly, but it works.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I just learned that ```obj.get()['Body'].read()``` will return bytes.

So, we need to add ```decode('utf-8')``` in order to extract.

```obj.get()['Body'].read().decode('utf-8') ```

Comment: Edited, take a look. @Nunu